The deployed GitHub Pages is not reflecting my latest code
I’m experiencing an issue with my GitHub Pages deployment, where the deployed site is not reflecting the latest code in my repository. Despite confirming that the code on GitHub is updated, the live site remains unchanged.
Steps Taken So Far
Here’s what I’ve tried to resolve the issue:

Confirmed Code Update: Checked the main branch (the one set up to deploy on GitHub Pages) to ensure it contains the latest code.
Cleared Browser Cache: Cleared the browser cache to rule out any local caching issues.
Forced Cache Refresh: Added <meta> tags in the index.html to prevent caching:

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />


Rebuilt and Redeployed: Rebuilt the project with npm run build and pushed the updated build files to GitHub.
Check GitHub Pages Deployment Status. Ensure that GitHub Pages is correctly set up to deploy from the main branch.
Force Push to GitHub. Try doing a force push:

git add .
git commit -m "Force update deployment"
git push origin main --force


Edit the test.js file on the GitHub website directly to see if it can force updating the deploying pages.

Observations

When I test the site locally, it reflects all the latest changes correctly.
After each update and deployment, the live site on GitHub Pages still shows an older version, even when I create new branches to deploy.

Additional Details

Repository URL: my GitHub repository
Branch Used for Deployment: main
Build Tool: React (Create React App)
Deployment Method: Direct GitHub Pages setup

Request for Help
Has anyone else encountered this issue with GitHub Pages not updating? Are there any specific troubleshooting steps or deployment settings that I might be overlooking? I’d appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this.
Thanks in advance for your help!

I’ve resolved the issue. I noticed that the deployment for the main branch kept getting stuck, even after multiple attempts to rerun all jobs. Since I couldn’t view what was happening in the backend, I tried deploying a gh-pages branch instead.
Here’s what I did:

Set up the gh-pages npm package to automate deploying only the build files to a gh-pages branch.
Updated my package.json with a "deploy" script:

"scripts": {
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}


Now, each time I want to update the live site, I just run npm run deploy. This process ensures that the gh-pages branch is kept in sync with the latest build, and GitHub Pages correctly reflects my updates now.

